# Matplotlib plots of all dataframe columns with FOR operator

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I want plot the graphs one by one from the dataframe with FOR operator.

```
names_list = df.columns.tolist()
for name in names_list:
    df[name].plot(figsize=(25, 5))
```

This code is no good. The graphs are depicted in one figure, but should be in different ones.
[image]

How can I get multiple charts instead of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
names_list = df.columns.tolist()
for name in names_list:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 5)) 
    df[name].plot(ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org) here's an example using a [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html):

```
import seaborn as sns, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [102]: df.head(3)
Out[102]: 
        Date  Consumption  Wind  Solar  Wind+Solar  name
0 2006-01-01     1069.184   NaN    NaN         NaN   mid
1 2006-01-02     1380.521   NaN    NaN         NaN   mid
2 2006-01-03     1442.533   NaN    NaN         NaN  high

g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df,col='name',col_wrap=1,hue='name')
g.fig.set_size_inches(6,3) # compressed just to show example
g.map(sns.lineplot,'Date','Consumption')
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Plots of all columns of a dataframe are required, but not one. But thanks for the option. It will be useful to me too.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm glad the other answer helped you!